# Laravel delete button not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-form

I was wondering if someone can look at this code and tell me why it's not working.  When I press the submit button, it will not submit.

```
 {!! Form::open([
     'method' => 'DELETE',
     'route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id],
     'style' => 'display: inline'
  ]) !!}

  {!! Form::submit('Delete this post?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I'm submitting it to a PostController's destory method, where the route is defined as 'posts'.

Route file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

});

Comment: Change `'method' => 'DELETE'` to `'method' => 'POST'`

Comment: @LarsMertens why do you think that would help?

Comment: I just tested your code, it's just fine and it is working here

Comment: @behz4d Was just about to reply the same thing. My comment was just a guess though. `Kaley36` Your code is fine, something else is happening which is not defined in the example above. Only thing i can still think of is `admin.posts.destroy` if that isn't it we need more information.

Comment: Even with an invalid route it should still post though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
{!! Form::open([
 'method' => 'DELETE',
 'route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id],
 'style' => 'display: inline'
 ]) !!}

 {!! Form::submit('Delete this post?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

To

```
{!! Form::open([
 'method' => 'DELETE',
 'route' => ['admin.posts.destroy', $post->id],
 'style' => 'display: inline'
  ]) !!}

 {!! Form::submit('Delete this post?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Following your prefix in route. Hope it would help

Comment: this is wrong, he is using Laravel HTML collective which automatically generates the hidden field for `'method' => 'DELETE',`, so he doesn't need to do it again with `{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}`, it's automatically there while using laravel HTML colelctive and a method like `DELETE`

Comment: Not sure what happened, but i cleared the cache and rewrote the form and now it works, even though its the same code.